# Google Charts (Pie) Showing Only Slivers when given dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to include a [Google Pie Chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) in my Rails app, and I've run into what I think is a particularly weird error.

The problem is, when I input numbers, the chart displays perfectly (showing my two input numbers as the two components of a pie equal to their sum), but when I try to feed it dynamic data, it seems to PICK UP the data but NOT USE it correctly -- instead displaying the two numbers as slivers in an otherwise blank chart. Code examples:

This works perfectly, turning into a pretty pie chart with the correct values (sold and left, below):

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var sold = 406;
    var left = 38; 
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Pounds', 'Sold/Left'],
      ['Pounds Sold', sold],
      ['Left', left]
    ]);

    var options = {

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

This, however, produces a chart with a hover showing (in this case) the exact same numbers (406, and 38), but the two chart sections are extremely small, accounting for about 1% of the chart's volume (as opposed to the ideal 100%). The remaining 99ish% of the chart is blank:

```
<div id="chart_div" data-sold=<%= @animal.pounds_sold.to_i %> data-left=<%= @animal.pounds_left.to_i %> ></div>
// Here, the numbers equal 406 and 38, as in the above. 

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var sold = $(document).find('#chart_div').attr('data-sold');
    var left = $(document).find('#chart_div').attr('data-left');
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Pounds', 'Sold/Left'],
      ['Pounds Sold', sold],
      ['Left', left]
    ]);

    var options = {

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

One possible clue is that when I hover over the sections in this erroring chart, although the hover says the right numbers (406, 38), it says these sections account for only 1 and 0.2 percent of the pie, respectively, even though the rest of the pie is blank (and has no hover/hover value).

Any ideas what's going on here? I'm guessing I'm committing some javascript/jquery crime, cause I'm fairly new to it, but I don't know what.

Thanks!

EDIT -- Another weird thing. I tried to see what would happen in a hybrid scenario with both dynamic numbers and straight numbers, i.e the below modification to the dynamic version above:

```
...
var other = 50;
var sold = $(document).find('#chart_div').attr('data-sold');
var left = $(document).find('#chart_div').attr('data-left');
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Pounds', 'Sold/Left'],
  ['Pounds Sold', sold],
  ['Left', left],
  ['Test', other]
]);
...
```

This, inexplicably (to me), led to NO CHART AT ALL.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are specifying the "values" of each sliver as a string. Try defining them as an `INT` and your pie should work